# Kubernetes pulling image from Jfrog Container Registry gives ImagePullBackOFF - x509

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes, minikube, jfrog-container-registry

I am working in my local dev environment

```
    OS:
       Ubuntu (bionic) 18.0.4 LTS    
    Minikube Version:
       v1.11.0
    Docker Version:
       19.03.10
```

I am using Jfrog Container Registry as registry to my minikube. I am able do the following:

1. docker login localhost:443 | or | ip-add:443
2. docker push ip-add:443/docker-local/test:latest
3. docker pull ip-add:443/docker-local/test:latest

I have configured Jfrog Container Registry to run behind Nginx Reverse Proxy listening on port 443. Created self-signed certs and Jfrog is using these certs.

Configured docker to use the self-signed certs as follows.

1. Create certs, copy it to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
2. sudo update-ca-certificates
3. copy the certificate to /etc/docker/cert.d/192.168.0.114:443/ca.crt
4. restarted the docker, just be sure

Configure K8 to use the docker login secret by .yaml file as following:

1. base64 encode ~/.docker/config.json
2. use it in the following template

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
 name: myregistrykey
 namespace: awesomeapps
data:
 .dockerconfigjson: UmVhbGx5IHJlYWxseSByZWVlZWVlZWVlZWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGx5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eSBsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbG9vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb25ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubmdnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2cgYXV0aCBrZXlzCg==
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

In the deployment.yaml, I use ImagePullSecrets and the name flag.

Now after all this setup where the docker pull is working on terminal, I get error on the pods saying x509 IP Sans.

I went through lot of documentation and K8 issues which was posted recently https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43924

replicated the steps didn't work out. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong? and how can I correct it.

Comment: Is your docker registry accessible from kubernetes nodes or cluster ? Check with telnet command from any of the nodes.

Comment: @JaskaranSingh ssh into the docker, and ran curl for the ip address 192.168.0.114 and it is working. I think the network is there, error in ssl-tls verification. The error, I am getting is this - x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.0.114 because it doesn't contain any IP Sans

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have a Docker on your host with JFrog Container Registry installed and additionally you have a minikube on your host that tries to connect to your registry? Could you tell more how did you create your certs?  Did you try to pull/push images directly with Docker from your minikube instance?

Comment: @DawidKruk You are right, I have docker installed in my base host system ubuntu. K8 installed by minikube and docker is installed in the base host system.

Docker pull/push is working in the host machine. After JaskaranSingh ssh idea. I went and put the ca cert using docker cp src-sys:host-sys and placed it in /etc/docker/certs.d/192.168.0.114:443/ca.cert